# Add quotes around each string in a list in jinja2?

Tags: python, template-engine, jinja2

The variable in Python :

```
names = ["a", "b"]
```

What I write currently in Jinja2 template:

```
c({{ names | join(",") }})
```

What I get using the template above:

```
c(a, b)
```

However, what I really need is:

```
c("a", "b")
```

I checked the document of Jinja2 but doesn't find a filter to do this. Does anyone have ideas about this in Jinja2?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If this is JavaScript code, have you considered JSONP?

Comment: @Blender It's R codes..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use custom filters for jinja2:

```
def surround_by_quote(a_list):
    return ['"%s"' % an_element for an_element in a_list]

env.filters["surround_by_quote"] = surround_by_quote
```

Comment: You might want to use `[repr(a) for a in a_list]` to correctly escape items which cointain special characters like `He said "Hello"`
`

Answer (score 0):

```
# some.py file
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# some.html file
{{ names|safe }}

# renders as the following, brackets included
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

To use as filter_plugin in ansible and pass pylint:

```py
''' From https://stackoverflow.com/a/68610557/571517 '''


class FilterModule():
    ''' FilterModule class must have a method named filters '''
    @staticmethod
    def surround_by_quotes(a_list):
        ''' implements surround_by_quotes for each list element '''
        return ['"%s"' % an_element for an_element in a_list]

    def filters(self):
        ''' returns a dictionary that maps filter names to
        callables implementing the filter '''
        return {'surround_by_quotes': self.surround_by_quotes}
```